# How print verbose log in a text file

Tags: java, tomcat, verbose

I want to print verbose log in a text file during tomcat startup. I tried to use
`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -verbose:class"` , but it prints in the console.
Can someone help me on this ?

Thanks

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/252934/how-to-redirect-tomcat-console-log-to-files-tomcat-started-via-windows-bat

is this answer for your question?